# Optionally using String.split(), split a string at the last occurance of a delimiter

Tags: java, regex, string, split, tokenize

I have a string that matches this regular expression: `^.+:[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/[0-9]+$` which can easily be visualized as `(Text):(Double)/(Int)`. I need to split this string into the three parts. Normally this would be easy, except that the `(Text)` may contain colons, so I cannot split on any colon - but rather the *last* colon.

The `.*` is greedy so it already does a pretty neat job of doing this, but this wont work as a regular expression into String.split() because it will eat my `(Text)` as part of the delimiter. Ideally I'd like to have something that would return a String[] with three strings. I'm 100% fine with not using String.split() for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use a straight up regular expression?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*):([\\d\\.]+)/(\\d+)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher( someString );
if (m.find()) {
  m.group(1); // returns the text before the colon
  m.group(2); // returns the double between the colon and the slash
  m.group(3); // returns the integer after the slash
}
```

Or similar. The pattern `^(.*):([\d\.]+)/(\d+)$` assumes that you actually have values in all three positions, and will allow just a period/fullstop in the double position, so you may want to tweak it to your specifications.

Comment: OK, now say that instead of using `[\d\.]+` to match the double, what if I wanted to be stringent and require `\d+(\.\d+)*`. Could I safely use only groups 0,1,3? That is to say, `sometext:other:2/4` and `sometext:other:2.0/4` sill group the same way?

Comment: It would be groups 1, 2 and 4, but you don't need to bother with that. Just make the new group a non-capturing one: `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Comment: group(0) returns the entire matched String. This is one of the few cases where the index does not start at zero. @AlanMoore has a good suggestion for a strict double regex.

Answer (score 5):

I don't like regex (just kidding I do but I'm not very good at it).

```
String s = "asdf:1.0/1"
String text = s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf(":"));
String doub = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(":")+1,text.indexOf("/"));
String inte = s.substring(text.indexOf("/")+1,s.length());
```

Comment: @Subs: I want to skip the initial `(`.

Comment: He said `()` for visualization purposes. Don't think those brackets come in

Comment: First mistake I ever made in my life.

Comment: This is similar to what I had previously, before I knew about the possibility of the extra colon. I feel regular expressions are needed to avoid future mishaps

Answer (score 1):

`String.split()` is typically used in simpler scenarios where the delimiter and formatting are more consistent and when you don't know how many elements you are going to be splitting.

Your use case calls for a plain old regular expression.  You know the formatting of the string, and you know you want to collect three values.  Try something like the following.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+):([0-9\\.]+)/([0-9]+)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
if (m.find()) {
    String myText = m.group(1);
    String myFloat = m.group(2);
    String myInteger = m.group(3);
}
```